# How to pull more than 500 user objects from my domain?

Tags: java, pagination, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to pull about 20,000 users from my Google domain. However, i know that Google only has a limit of about 500 users for a pull request. I know about the pageToken stuff, but the documentation for it online is terrible. Can someone show me how to use the pageToken? Please keep in mind i am using the google client libraries. This is what my code looks like so far:

```
@Test 
public void paginationTest() throws IOException, NullPointerException,      GeneralSecurityException { 
try { 


Directory directory = GCAuthentication.getDirectoryService("xxx", "vvv", dddd);
Directory.Users.List list = directory.users().list().setOrderBy("email").setMaxResults(500).setDomain("dev.royallepage.ca");

do { 
com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Users users = list.execute();
java.util.List<User> uL = users.getUsers(); 
//uL.addAll(users.getUsers());
//list.setPageToken(list.getPageToken()); 
System.out.println(uL.size());
}while (list.getPageToken() != null && list.getPageToken().length() > 0); 

}catch(NullPointerException e) { 

}
```

}

Please advise what i am doing wrong! Thanks,

Mesam

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a function that will get the `pageToken` variable then call another request including the `nextPageToken`.

> Use the **`pageToken`** query string for responses with large number of groups. In the case of pagination, the response returns the **`nextPageToken`** property which gives a token for the next page of response results. Your next request uses this token as the **`pageToken`** query string value.

Sample Code Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
?domain=primary domain name&pageToken=token for next results page
&maxResults=max number of results per page
&orderBy=email, givenName, or familyName
&sortOrder=ascending or descending
&query=email, givenName, or familyName:the query's value*
```

Hope this helps!